# Чтение папок с использованием буфера и общее ускорение процесса доступа к папкам

Tags: файловая-система, java

Как в Java можно (и можно ли) получить список папок раздела с использованием буфера чтения как это делается с обычными файлами с помощью java.io.BufferedInputStream ? Попытка подставить конструктору буфера параметр - java.io.FileInputStream c параметром в последем в виде объекта типа "java.io.File" файла нужной папки выдаёт FileNotFoundException, что и понятно ибо, как написано в документации к FileInputStream: *Throws: 

    FileNotFoundException - if the file does not exist, is a **directory rather than a regular file**, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading.* Как ещё можно ускорить доступ к папкам раздела? Спасибо. :)

Comment: @Jaguar_UA_kh, ну что вам стоит показать ваш код?

Answer (score 1):

Не понял, у вас список директорий в разделе (другой директории) слишком медленно формируется?

Вроде он и так целиком отдаётся:

```
File[] files = new File("/home/you/Desktop").listFiles()
```

**UPD:**

[[@Jaguar_UA_kh](/users/17149/jaguar_ua_kh)](/users/17149/jaguar_ua_kh)
Вот здесь вы получаете список файлов в директории и получаете его целиком - это значит буфер ненужен (его и быть не может).

```
currentPath.listFiles()
```

Вот тут:

```
if(x.isDirectory()) {
    currentPath = x;
    search(currentPath);
}
```

У вас рекурсия - ООП не любит рекурсию. Попробуйте заменить на [поиск в ширину](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83) или [глубину](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83).
Не факт, что ускорит (ускорит только если большая глубина вложенности каталогов), но точно стек не переполнит.

Comment: Не знаю насколько медленно то время за которое я получаю список всех директорий раздела, но всегда хочется большего. Вот, например, при использовании буфера для чтения файлов, скорость чтения явно увеличивается. Можно ли достичь такого же ускорения и с получением списка папок? Простите, не понял что вы имели ввиду: "Вроде он и так целиком отдаётся:"? Кто, куда, кому отдаётся? :)

Comment: @Jaguar_UA_kh, я имел введу тот код который привёл.

Покажите как вы получаете список директорий в java коде.

Comment: void search(File currentPath)
{
 try
 {
  if (currentPath.listFiles().length==0)
System.out.println(currentPath.getAbsolutePath());
  for(File x:currentPath.listFiles())
  {
   if(x.isDirectory())
   {
    currentPath = x;
    search(currentPath);
    }
   }
  }
 catch(NullPointerException npe){System.err.println(currentPath);}
}

Comment: /*currentPath = "C:"*/

Comment: @Jaguar_UA_kh
Дополнил ответ